# React event fire when go to next input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

How I can detect input change when a sentence ends.
when I use onChange, state changes realtime but I want to change state when a sentence end or after few seconds.

Comment: Maybe you should try `onFocusOut`?

Comment: use `onBlur` instead of `onChange`

Comment: @RishabhMishra No I want fire that event "only" when focus out of the input.

Comment: then try @Kinduser solution

Comment: @RishabhMishra there is no event for "onFocusOut"

Comment: try onBlur https://www.peterbe.com/plog/onchange-in-reactjs

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions, solution one listens for the key up event on the input and will only update the state if a period or enter key is pressed. Solution two only updates the state if you focus out of the input. Click the CodePen link to see a running example of the two solutions: https://codepen.io/w7sang/pen/zzbQzQ?editors=1111

```js
// App
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sentence: null
    }
    this.handleKeyUp = this.handleKeyUp.bind(this);
    this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);
  }
  handleKeyUp(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode === 190 || evt.keyCode === 13) {
      this.setState({
        sentence: evt.target.value
      });
    }
  }
  handleBlur(evt) {
    this.setState({
      sentence: evt.target.value
    })
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h5>Sentence: (Start typing on any of the solution inputs)</h5>
        {this.state.sentence}
        <div>
          <h5>Solution 1: On KeyUp (To update state, you must press period `.` or enter)</h5>
          <input onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <h5>Solution 2: On Blur</h5>
          <input onBlur={this.handleBlur} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('app'));
```